# running jshell in jdk-17 java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible

Tags: java, java-17, java-module, jshell

I am running **jshell** like this

```
jdk-17/bin/jshell --class-path $(echo lib/*.jar | tr ' ' ':') -J--add-opens=java.base/java.time=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I am getting this exception:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @75cd8043
```

Why doesn't jshelll pick up the jvm argument passed in?

Thanks

Comment: did you try adding `-J--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED`?